# Code Example: String comparison with .equals(args[0])

Tags: java

I'm learning Java with the help of a book and don't understand the following example/statement:

For `args[0].equals("Schrödinger")` you need to make sure the `args[0]` is not null, whereas `"Schrödinger".equals(args[0])` doesn't need this kind of check because `"Schrödinger"` can't be null.

Code:

```
if("Schrödinger".equals(args[0])) {
    System.out.println("Hallo");
}
```

However I do get an error if there is no parameter in `args`, which also seems logical as you need to grab the value at `args[0]` at some point for the comparison, even if the string `"Schrödinger"` isn't null. I'm confused, is the example from the book wrong or am I not understanding something?

Comment: The code shown here only handles `args[0]` being null, not `args` having a length of `0`.

Comment: The example is bad since using `args[0]` brings its own problem. Your assumptions are correct. The point of the book is that it's always preferable to call `equals` on a definitely-not-null value since it saves the null check.

Comment: @hev1 I'm not sure I understand what you mean - how is this code handling args[0] being null when I get an "Index 0 out of bounds for length 0" error for it. Do you mean there should be a check if 0 < args.length before that? At least that's what I would expect, but there is no such check in the example code

Comment: @EmiliyanaKalinova In that case `args[0]` is not null; rather, `args` is an array with a length of `0`.

Comment: You need an extra check: `if(args.length != 0 && "Schrödinger".equals(args[0]))`

Comment: That example is very unfortunate as by default `args[0]` will never be `null` unless it will be **explicitly modified** by application, because `args` simply stores arguments passed while starting `java.exe` or `javaw.exe` process, like `java full.name.of.SomeClass foo bar` in which case `args` will hold array containing `["foo", "bar"]` elements. If there would be no arguments like `java full.name.of.SomeClass` then `args` will hold *empty array* `[]` (with length 0) not `null` (nor `[null, null]` because application doesn't know how many arguments are expected and are missing).

Comment: Anyway main idea behind that example is probably to show that `"foo".equals(null)` will return `false` while `null.equals("foo")` will throw NullPointerException because `null` doesn't have any methods (not even those from Object class)

Comment: Exactly my point regarding the extra check :-) How is args[0] not null if the array has a length of 0? I thought it is similar to initiating a variable but not assigning a value to it - it exists, but its value is null. Since args is always existent as part of the program (right?), but no value has been assigned to the 0 index, the "value" of args[0] should be null or is there an error in my reasoning?

Comment: When there will be no arguments, then `args` will hold empty array (array without any elements). It is like `String[] args = new String[0];` OR `String[] args = {}`. Such array has no available indexes to store any data, so using `args[0]` will not return `null` but throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Just like `String[] array = {"foo","bar"};` for `array[1]` will return `"bar"` but for `array[2]` will also throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because valid index is never greater than array size (like for `new int[10]` valid index range is [0]..[9], using [10] is not valid).

Answer (score 1):

The code provided in the book only handles `args[0]` being `null`, not `args` having a length of `0`. Assuming your program is supposed to pass some command-line arguments to it, and you do not pass any argument while executing it, the length of the following array, `args` will remain `0`.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

As a result, an attempt to access an element from the first position, which is specified with the index, `0` will result in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Since the index of an array starts with `0`, the maximum index can go up to the size of the array minus `1`.

You can avoid the problem you have faced by checking the size of the array first before accessing an element within the maximum index e.g.

```
if(args.length >= 1 && "Schrödinger".equals(args[0])) {
   //...
}
```

Similarly, if you want to access an element up the index, `1`, you should check if the size is `2` or more e.g.

```
if(args.length >= 2 && "Schrödinger".equals(args[1])) {
   //...
}
```

By the way, a condition like `"Schrödinger".equals(args[0])` is known as [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct. For the main method If the array is not provided then you can not access the first element of the array. It will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since there are no elements.

Answer (score 0):

> For `args[0].equals("Schrödinger")` you need to make sure the `args[0]` is not null.

True, since you're calling `.equals("Schrödinger")` on the object, which is expected to be at index 0 in the `args` array.

> whereas `"Schrödinger".equals(args[0])` doesn't need this kind of check because `"Schrödinger"` can't be null.

True, as `"Schrödinger"` is a String literal, which by definition is an Object, so you explicitly have it, and there's no even hypothetical chance it'll be *null*.

> However I do get an error if there is no parameter in args, which also seems logical as you need to grab the value at `args[0]` at some point for the comparison, even if the string "Schrödinger" isn't null.

True, but to be precise here, error doesn't happen at the comparison stage, because of you can't compare something to *nothing*, rather, your *error* happens here, because you're not passing anything, hence the `args` array is empty, and `args[0]` will throw the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

I hope I made each and every step clear for you.

Answer (score 0):

Running any method for a null object is not allowed, and you will get an exception. You have to check if `args[0]` is null (or of length 0) before you do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

#### For User defined args array

**Case 1**: `args[0].equals("Schrödinger")`
When args[0] is null(no value is passed), you **cannot call equals method on
null** hence `NullPointerException` is thrown

**Case 2**: `"Schrödinger".equals(args[0])`
In this case despite args[0] being null equals is called on string literal and
no exception is thrown + the condition evaluates to false. Hence this approach
is the recommended one or use Optionals.

#### For args of public static void main

In case of args array of  public static void main it will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. If JVM finds no command line arguments its initializes the args as String[] args = new String[0] i.e of length 0. Hence while accessing it throws exception

Comment: But I do get an Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 exception for case 2 and (according to some other comments) args[0] isn't null when the array is empty. Case 2 doesn't evaluate to false.

Comment: Ok i assumed it as user defined array, In case of args array of public static void main it will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. if JVM finds no command line arguments its initializes the args as String[] args = new String[0] i.e of length 0. Let me know if it helps